# How to set some EnvironmentVariable to the dir where app is executed\somedir?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, window, environment-variables

So I want to set 100% garanteed empty user enviroment variable (via [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686206%28VS.85%29.aspx) ) to the dir where app is executed\somedir. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [GetEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683187%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function to retrieves the environment variables for the current process, then call [SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686206%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). MSDN provided a sample code to demonstrate how to do that. 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682009(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682009%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)